# Mac app NSArrayController bindings not autosaving Core Data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I was under the impression that when using bindings (been following this tutorial despite being outdated. http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php - You can use it to see what I'm doing) the Persistent Store would automagically save the changes you make. In fact, though it was hours ago and I wouldn't be surprised if I'm now going mad, I got it working, and when I made a change it would persist on rebuilding the app.

However, the test app I've built following the tutorial no longer saves and despite showing the changes I make within the app, they disappear once I re-run the app. I've been checking the `Core Data` debug menu and nothing happens when I press the "+" button which is set up to the "Add" method of my `NSArrayController`. I know it's accessing my data model too as my textField for the Title (again, see the tutorial so you know what I'm referring to) adopts the default text I put in the DataModel section. The only thing missing therefore is the actual saving.

So my real question is, based on the tutorial, what part of the bindings actually makes the `managedObjectContext` save? Is there a flag or something that isn't checked?

I don't know if it's important or not, but there were differences between the tutorial and my project, mainly that the `NSArrayControllers` are bound to "`App Delegate`"with a Model Key Path of "`self.managedObjectContext`". Also, I removed all the relationships in an attempt to whittle down the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Mike

**UPDATE:** Here are some pictures that show the bindings.
How I set up the `NSArrayController`:[image][image]

Here is how is how my `Data Model` Looks:
[image][image]

Lastly, this is how I set up the `TextFields` to update the `NSArrayControllers`:
[image][image]
[image][image]

I hope this helps to get a an ideas as to the set up.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Basically the Cocoa Bindings handle the saving when the array controller is set up correctly. There's no more magic. It's a bit hard to understand what you've done and what you've changed. Some screenshots and code would help. Did it work and then stopped or did it never work?

Comment: @SAE Oh ok, so potentially I've got an incorrectly set up array. I'll look into it then. It had worked previously but I changed the the Data Model (literally only changed a relationship from `many` to `one`) then it stopped, and that was it. I'll post some code tomorrow as it's a bit late now (1:30am).

Comment: @SAE Hey, I've just uploaded the images of the set up, what do you think? Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check to make sure you've copied all the Core Data boiler-plate code from the source code of the tutorial you mentioned.

Specifically this part in the App Delegate:

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender {
    NSError *error;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context;
    int reply = NSTerminateNow;

    context = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (context != nil) {
        if ([context commitEditing]) {
            if (![context save:&error]) {

                // This default error handling implementation should be changed to make sure the error presented includes application specific error recovery. For now, simply display 2 panels.
                BOOL errorResult = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];

                if (errorResult == YES) { // Then the error was handled
                    reply = NSTerminateCancel;
                } else {

                    // Error handling wasn't implemented. Fall back to displaying a "quit anyway" panel.
                    int alertReturn = NSRunAlertPanel(nil, @"Could not save changes while quitting. Quit anyway?" , @"Quit anyway", @"Cancel", nil);
                    if (alertReturn == NSAlertAlternateReturn) {
                        reply = NSTerminateCancel;  
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            reply = NSTerminateCancel;
        }
    }
    return reply;
}
```

If it's there, changes will be saved when the app is terminated normally. Pressing the 'stop' button in Xcode will terminate the app immediately, without going through the method mentioned above.

My guess is that you are not going mad, but first exited the app properly and have been pressing the 'stop' button later ;).

Comment: Man, bang on. Thank you so much; it's good to know I'm not going mad! Mike.